# I am trying to validate XML against XMLSchema( XSD), below is the error I got for the code I have. May I know where I am going wrong?

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd, xml-validation

Below is the code I have for validating XML file with XSD file.

```
public class XmlXsdValidation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String xsdPath = "D://tmp/xsdFile.xsd";
        final String xmlPath = "D://tmp/xmlFile.xml";

        File xsdFile = new File(xsdPath);
        File xmlFile = new File(xmlPath);

        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        try {
            javax.xml.validation.Schema xmlSchema = factory.newSchema(xsdFile);
            Validator validator = xmlSchema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xmlFile));
            System.out.println("Sucess....");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Below is the xmlFile.xml content:

```
<s11:Envelope xmlns:s11='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <s11:Body>
    <ns1:LanguageName xmlns:ns1='http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo'>
      <ns1:sISOCode>abk</ns1:sISOCode>
    </ns1:LanguageName>
  </s11:Body>
</s11:Envelope>
```

Below is the xsdFile.xsd content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" targetNamespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="Envelope">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Body" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element name="LanguageNameResponse" minOccurs="0">
                                <xsd:complexType mixed="true">
                                    <xsd:sequence>
                                        <xsd:element name="LanguageNameResult" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:normalizedString" />
                                    </xsd:sequence>
                                </xsd:complexType>
                            </xsd:element>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

OutPut( Error message):
file:/D:/tmp/xmlFile.xml; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 83; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ns1:LanguageName'. One of '{"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/":LanguageNameResponse}' is expected.

WSDL file considered:
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/file_details/wsdl/examples/country.wsdl

Comment: Are you sure about these file contents? Because i don't see the namespace "m" that is mentioned in the validation errors.

Comment: Your XSD does not resemble the structure of your XML. Your XSD contains elements like `LanguageNameResponse` and `LanguageNameResult`, but your XML has some other elements, namely `LanguageName` and `sISOCode`. So, this won't validate for sure, apart from the namespace issues.

Answer (score 0):

The SOAP envelope and the SOAP body are in different namespaces. You need one schema document for each namespace, with appropriate `xs:import` links connecting them. Each element must be declared in the schema document with the correct `targetNamespace`.